# Best Option create file and move or create on remote ftp

Tags: php, ftp

My php application must create 2 copies of 12000 optimised jpgs, 1 copy of each on 2 different servers.

Am I best to create the images on my server then move them, or create them on the remote ftp's.

Both would be using php ftp functions.

Comment: How would you plan on "creating" them on the remote FTP server?  Unless you have some method of making one of the FTP servers download it from the other, you'll have to send out all the image data twice (once for each).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the option, whenever possible, I use PHP shell commands to run rsync, performance wise it's the fastest. if that's not an option, then creating once and copying them seperately  would probably be the more efficient if it is a one-time or limited make/copy.

If on the other hand, these images would be made/remade repeatedly, then I would run the image create scripts independently on the two boxes.